# cleverhans module not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, cleverhans

i am ruining below code, but it show me an error.
i tried different methods to install  cleverhans, it get installed but still show error.

## Install bleeding edge version of cleverhans

!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans.git#egg=cleverhans

import cleverhans

print("Cleverhans Version: " + cleverhans.**version**)

error-

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
3 get_ipython().system('pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans.git#egg=cleverhans')
4
----> 5 import cleverhans
6 import tensorflow as tf
7 import numpy as np

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleverhans'**

Comment: What python version are you using? Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20 os i am using . and python 3.8 version.

Comment: This code does not show any error when I tried replicating the same code in Google Colab. and shows the output  - `Cleverhans Version: 4.0.0-242afd7ec8f9546baeb1168438446ce1`. However, could you please try again using this code line - `!pip install git+https://github.com/CNOCycle/cleverhans.git@feature/tf2.x`. Let us know if issue still persists.